# How can I get the tap gesture animation in a MAUI control?

Tags: .net, xaml, animation, mobile, maui

How can I get the tap animation on a control the same way as Jetpack compose does the clickable modifier. In Jetpack compose when you set the clickable modifier the control will have a very nice tap animation.

In MAUI, I tried to use the TapGestureRecognizer. Sure it gets the event or bind to a command which is good. But I don't get the animation on the control.

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Padding="8" Background="red">
      <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
      </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
      <HorizontalStackLayout>
        <Image Source="settings.svg" HeightRequest="16" WidthRequest="16" />
        <Label Text="SETTINGS" />
      </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </Grid>
```

How can I get that tap animation in a Maui control without using a button?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to set the animation of the `Grid` by using the `TapGestureRecognizer `?

Comment: Yes if that is possible. If not, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use my FreakyEffects package for it if you are still looking for a solution: https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyEffects

In the wiki, there is a quick guide on usage https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyEffects/wiki/TouchEffect

There is also a usage guide in this blog https://medium.com/@freakyali/adding-native-click-effects-in-net-maui-dd3159a4b709

All you need to do to use it as simple as adding this namespace:

```
xmlns:freakyEffects="clr-namespace:Maui.FreakyEffects.TouchEffects;assembly=Maui.FreakyEffects"
```

And then adding it to any layout:

```
 <ContentView
 .
 .
 .
 .
 freakyEffects:TouchEffect.Color="Green"/>
```

***Note that it adds native animations so iOS will have a fade kind of effect and Android will have a ripple***

Answer (score 0):

For the Ripple effect in MAUI you want to achieve(like the clickable modifier in Jetpack compose), you need the `TouchEffect`, however, this hasn't been implemented yet and there is a proposal:[TouchEffect](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues/86) to address this in the [MAUI Community Toolkit](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui). You can comment in the proposal to add the Ripple effect of the control.

For now, you can use [MAUI Handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/?view=net-maui-7.0) to change ripple effect for button on Android like below:

```
 
 Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ButtonHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyRippleCustomization", (handler, view) =>
{
#if ANDROID

    if (handler.PlatformView.Background is Android.Graphics.Drawables.RippleDrawable ripple )
       { 
            ripple.SetColor(Android.Content.Res.ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.Gray));
        };

#endif
});
```

Comment: Not looking for a rotation animation. I would like to have a ripple effect like when tapping on a button. I would like to attach that kind of effect on a regular container such as grid or a frame.

Comment: @C0NTRERAS Thanks for the response, you can see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. I'll keep this post open until there's an update on MAUI.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll also keep an eye on it.